# Howto embed a custom non-visible HTML5 data attribute in a Freemarker template?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I would like to define a [custom data-* attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) in an Spring form tag:

```
<@form.input path="endDate" data-tralaaa="moin"/>
```

Unfortunately Freemarker doesn't like this. Anyone a clue? I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "-" at line 24, column 114 in WEB-INF/views/reisenachsendung/period.ftl.
```

Was expecting:
    "=" ...

I would like to produce a HTML5 valid page. So *dataTralaaa* is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** As of 2.3.22, you can use `-` (and `.` and `:`) as part of any name if you precede it with a `\`, like in `<@form.input  data\-tralaaa="moin">`. (It's not too cute, but `-` is already used as subtraction operator, and fixing this wouldn't backward compatible, and so must wait for a major FTL version increase.)

The problem is that you can't use dash in parameter names. This is a syntactical restriction. But that's maybe only half of the problem. Does Spring's @form.input accept parameters that it doesn't know and inserts them into the HTML tag? Because if it doesn't, then the whole dash issue doesn't mater.